# How to process packet captures with Python's dpkt module

Tags: python, dpkt

I am trying to write a python program to parse packet capture using dpkt module. I have used it on packet captures that had Ethernet and tcpdump captures and it worked fine. However, my current packet capture is raw packet capture that directly has IP header and subsequent protocols and it seems like dpkt is not able to understand these captures. Picture of capture file is attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHsdn.png)

The code I had was

```
f = open(ipfile, 'rb')

pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts,buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf) //Also tried with eth = dpkt.sll.SLL(buf), but no luck.
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data
```

Any ideas on how to parse such captures?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with CAIDA pcap. Try

```
ip = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
```